# Multiple dependencies when trying to achieve the third normal form

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Imagine I got the following DB:

```
a          //primary key
b
c
d
```

At such the following functional dependencies are valid:

```
a -> bcd
b -> cd
c -> bd
```

Wht should I do to pass it to the third normal form?

I tried to separate as follows:

```
a -> b          //this b is the foreing key to the b of the other tables
b -> c
b -> d
```

Is it correct?

Comment: You don't separate the dependencies, you separate the tables. You should split the original table R(a,b,c,d) into two tables (let's say R1 and R2). Have you done that? Just to clarify what you probably already know: a,b,c and d are columns in one table.

Comment: What happened to the FD c->bd?

Comment: @SimoKivistö the new relations are, in fact, new tables. Sorry for not letting it clear.

Comment: Ok, then give the tables as R1, R2, etc, and give all of them. (a, b, c, d) already means something specific.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about it the wrong way. You do not play around with the dependencies (unless this is some toy HW problem that specifically tells you to); you want to split the table up so that all tables are in 3NF. In your case, this would be (I think!!):

*a*b

*b*c

*c*d

Where the italicized letter represents a key. Now, an example of why you do not play with dependencies:

Say this database was of people and held their SS, BDate, and Name. You could then say that SS -> BDate, Name, since it is pretty much true that your SS number is unique to you. Now, when you play around with dependencies, you play around with what the data *means*. It's not really up to you to say that SS number can determine your name; it simply is. Saying SS -> BDate and eliminating the Name attribute is simply false.

Similarly, with your database, although ABCD don't mean anything, their dependencies are fixed and not to be changed. So, that was my super long way of saying: **split the tables, don't touch the dependencies!!** =)

Comment: It isn't super long.  +1 for stressing *meaning*.  Wannabe theoreticians these days abstract things to the point that it loses its meaning, and then they wonder why they are confused.